# Weblogic config restores wrong old files on boot

Tags: weblogic

I'm installing a new weblogic domain for an environment from a source env and once I configure everything in the config.xml and the surrounding domain config files I start the admin and everything is fine. The settings in the domain are correct.

Then I start one of the JVMs and during boot the old config.xml (from source env) appears along with its backups and uses the old config.xml.

Why does that happen?

I tried deleting domain_bak in servers dir, I cleaned JVM cache but the old files still get restored. I see them listed in domain_bak's file **deleted_files_index** but only their names are there, nothing more.

What to do??

Thanks.

Comment: did you change the config settings from the console, or you change it directly by FTP or Text editor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when you give the wrong url of the admin server.
ie if you have 2 domains with the admin of first domain listening on 7001 and admin of domain 2 listening on 8001. If you accidentally start a managed server of domain 2 with the admin url of domain 1 then the config from domain 1 will be copied to domain 2.

Hope this makes sense.

In essence check what you are giving for startmanagedweblogic.cmd